# setRequestProperty in loop (map)

Tags: java, dictionary, properties, request, connection

Where am I doing wrong?

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : header.entrySet()) {                  
          conn.setRequestProperty("\""+entry.getKey()+"\",\""+entry.getValue()+"\"");
      }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using method `#setRequestProperty(String, String)` from class [`java.net.URLConnect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), or its derived classes, and your code does not compile. This method takes 2 input parameters, `key` and `value`. You need to provide them separately:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : header.entrySet()) {                  
    conn.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```